# How to Debug nuget package in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget-package

It is possible to debug your own nuget packages using symbols in *.snupkg files. Visual Studio gives you the possibility to setup Symbol Servers such as Azure Devops Artifacts.

Here's example how to do it in Visual Studio: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-external-sources-with-visual-studio/

Is it possible to do something similar in VS Code as well?

I'd expect a functionality of step into method that comes from a package created in a separate solution.

Comment: `.snupkg` (and `.symbols.nupkg`) are both kinda old-fashioned now - thesedays we use `<DebugType>embedded` and that's all you need.